# Example of using Mule ESB to route web service calls

Tags: java, web-services, soap, esb, mule

I'm looking for an example of how to set up a very simple Mule configuration to route a SOAP web service call from a client to a service provider.  Initially, there will just be one provider, and then I will want to add multiple service providers and a round-robin routing strategy in Mule.

Most of the examples on the Mule site have the service provider running within the Mule container.  I want mine to be completely external.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to decompose message arguments use HTTP pass-through, which is more light-weight and a lot simpler. For the round-robin implementation you could use a filter router with a groovy-based filter expression.

See here:

[Create pass through with Mule ESB 2.2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094757/create-pass-through-with-mule-esb-2-2-1)

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE2USER/Outbound+Routers#OutboundRouters-Filters